# Maven site (Maven 3) generates empty site folder

Tags: java, maven, javadoc, maven-javadoc-plugin, maven-site-plugin

I'm attempting to create a basic maven site using the maven site plugin. So I added this to my pom:

```
<reporting>
    <plugins>
        <!--JavaDoc setup-->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.7</version>
            <configuration>
                <defaultAuthor>Leon Blakey</defaultAuthor>
                <defaultVersion>${project.version}</defaultVersion>
                <links>
                    <link>http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api</link>
                </links>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</reporting>
```

And ran `mvn site --errors`

```
[INFO] Error stacktraces are turned on.
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building pircbotx 1.3-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-site-plugin:2.0.1:site (default-site) @ pircbotx ---
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.688s
[INFO] Finished at: Wed Jan 12 18:08:00 EST 2011
[INFO] Final Memory: 5M/13M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
W:\programming\pircbot-hg>
```

Hmm, odd that there's no output. So when I check target/site, its empty. The only folders are images/ , css/ , and WEB-INF/ , filled with some generic pictures. No javadoc and no site.

This is reproducible with `mvn site:site` and `mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:2.2:site` (apparently maven only wants to use 2.0.1 by default)

Whats strange is that I can go back to maven 2.2.1 and successfully generate a site. But when I use 3.0.1-RC1 (happens to come with Netbeans), it fails.

What am I doing wrong that would make the site plugin fail in 3.0.1 but not 2.2.1?

Comment: Not that this will help you, but I had the same problem with 3.0 and figured it was a maven bug.  I never did get the site generated.

Comment: Check https://cwiki.apache.org/MAVEN/maven-3x-and-site-plugin.html to see if that helps as well

Comment: @Raghuram these days I think the link you provided about Maven 3 and site plugin is detailed at this page instead: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-site-plugin/maven-3.html

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Perhaps you can try using [Maven Site Plugin 3.x](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-site-plugin/maven-3.html).  You can do that by adding the following in your pom.xml

```
<build>
    ...
    <plugins>
        ...
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0-beta-3</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Yes, using 3.0-beta-3 plugin definitely causes maven to actually work, but it irks me to use a plugin version with -beta in it.

Comment: Will this break if I use Maven 2? I migrate between 2.2.1 and 3.0.1

Comment: @TheLQ. Yes. This version of the plugin requires maven 3

Comment: Well this works in Maven 3. Guess I just have to use that. Thanks for the help

Comment: If you want this to work in both Maven 2 and 3 (this was a requirement for working with my CI server) you need to put it in a profile. I find that this activation section seems to give workable results: `<activation><file><exists>${basedir}</exists></file></activation>`

Comment: @Jesse A demonstration of what was 'irking' you is trying to understand [this](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-site-plugin/maven-3.html) page released further down the track. Seems things changed a little after beta

Answer (score 8):

I was having the same problem.  I found a [blog post](http://www.wakaleo.com/blog/site-generation-in-maven-3) about the topic.

Quoting the blog (emphasis mine):

> If you have been using the reporting section of the pom.xml file to generate code quality metrics, javadoc reports, and so forth, you may have a little work to do to migrate this feature into Maven 3. Indeed, the reporting and reportSets sections have been deprecated (**it won't cause an error with Maven 3, it will just be ignored**), and have been replaced by a reportPlugins section in the configuration block of the maven-site-plugin itself.

Ignoring the old `<reporting>` without any warning about it being deprecated seems a bit rude, but anyway...

> So you are basically just moving your old reporting plugins into the configuration section of the new maven-site-plugin.

A [section of the maven-plugin-site](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-site-plugin/maven-3.html) explains that they [removed of all reporting logic from the core of Maven](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNG-4162) to "decouple the Maven core from Doxia and to allow arbitrary reporting systems to be developed."  Makes sense.

Comment: Yea, that's why everything broke and why Site 3 is required

Answer (score 7):

Use of the Site Plugin ( http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-site-plugin/ ) with Maven 3 finally seems to be resolved. The (non-beta) version has been released, and the ability to use the version 2 style `<reporting>` structure in the pom.xml declaration has been added back.

Although it is (as usual) hard to navigate the substantial but unorganized and overlapping documentation about Maven 3 and the site plugin, one page - http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-site-plugin/maven-3.html - states that the old style is now recommended over the new "plugin to site plugin" style:

> **Note:** In Maven 3, the new format does not support report plugins configuration inheritance: see MSITE-484. This format was technically necessary to remove reporting logic from Maven 3, but a new inheritance mechanism still needs to be added to Maven 3 to make it as flexible as the old format. So the new format is not ready for direct use for now.

The example page http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-site-plugin/examples/configuring-reports.html for configuring reports doesn't even mention the "new" formatting method.

Not sure if this is in a "best practice" form, but an example pom reporting section that works for me with a couple of extra reports is as follows; select your own plugins as desired.

```
    ...
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0</version>
          </plugin>
       </plugins>
    </build>

    <reporting>
        <plugins>

            <!-- Default Site Pages -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
            </plugin>

            <!-- Java Documentation -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.8</version>
            </plugin>

            <!-- Source Code Cross-Reference -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jxr-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
            </plugin>
            ...
        </plugins>
    </reporting>
```

As an aside, If you use the m2e plugin in Eclipse to edit your POMs, then you can use code completion in the version section of a plugin to give you a list of its current versions. Very handy.