# Maven: version plugin failes with RenderingContext class missing message

Tags: maven

I want to run mvn versions:dependency-updates-report to generate a report of new dependencies versions. When I run it from command line I get

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.codehaus.mojo:versions-maven-plugin:2.1:dependency-updates-report
>   (default-cli) on project PROJECT_NAME: Execution default-cli of goal
>   org.codehaus.mojo:versions-maven-plugin:2.1:dependency-updates-report
>   failed: A required class was missing while executing
>   org.codehaus.mojo:versions-maven-plugin:2.1:dependency-updates-report:
>   org/apache/maven/doxia/module/xhtml/decoration/render/RenderingContext

Looks like 2.1 is the most fresh version available. Also I use:

> Apache Maven 3.2.3 
>   Java version: 1.6.0_45, vendor: Sun Microsystems
>   Inc. OS name: "windows 7"

Whats wrong?

Update:
same story with empty POM and Maven 2.2.1
Is there a single person who was able to run this goal? :)

UPDATE 2

My POM ran with Maven 2 or 3:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.javagames.app</groupId>
    <artifactId>MavenGames</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <reporting>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>versions-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1</version>
                <reportSets>
                    <reportSet>
                        <reports>
                            <report>dependency-updates-report</report>
                            <report>plugin-updates-report</report>
                            <report>property-updates-report</report>
                        </reports>
                    </reportSet>
                </reportSets>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </reporting>
</project>
```

Comment: Had there been download before the output of the error message? If yes check them if the download has worked without any problem..Are you behind a proxy etc.?

Comment: yes, the downloads work fine. we have our own repository and its completely accessible.

Comment: Can you show your full pom file?

Comment: khmarbaise, it doesn't matter. It is the same in a POM which is absolutely empty. I am sure you will get the same in your system.

Comment: It does matter, cause this goal needs a project which means usually can't be simple called from command line. If you do it within a reporting environment it works without any problem. See here https://github.com/khmarbaise/smpp/blob/master/pom.xml#L553

Comment: I have added my POM. Neither versions plugin nor site:site do not work in my case. Please tell me if my POM is ok and which command should evaluate dependencies-update report.

Comment: To create a report you should use `mvn site`

Comment: Here is an answer to all my troubles :)

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4675175/maven-site-maven-3-generates-empty-site-folder